# Plotting equal area map around a given Lat-Long using Cartopy

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I want to have a square map around a user input latitude and longitude.

```py
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import cartopy.feature  
from cartopy.mpl.gridliner import LONGITUDE_FORMATTER, LATITUDE_FORMATTER
x=float(input('Enter latitude:'))
y=float(input('Enter longitude:')) 

ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.set_extent([y-10,y+10,x-10,x+10],ccrs.PlateCarree())

ax.coastlines()
ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

It's a good plot
This works if I don't go towards the poles-

[image: Its a good plot]

The sphericity of the earth is not taken count here and it stops at 90 degree -

[image: The sphericity of the earth is not taken count here and it stops at 90 degree]

If I change the projection to orthographic, the pole problem may be resolved.

```py
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import cartopy.feature  
from cartopy.mpl.gridliner import LONGITUDE_FORMATTER, LATITUDE_FORMATTER
 
x=float(input('Enter latitude:'))
y=float(input('Enter longitude:')) 

ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Orthographic(y,x))
ax.set_extent([y-10,y+10,x-10,x+10],ccrs.PlateCarree())


ax.coastlines()
ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True)

plt.show()
```

I think the sphericity is taken into account, and I may get a good square plot, when I am near the equator. But, as I approach the poles, the square will start shrinking, and eventually I will not get a good area, as I have to take latitudes and longitudes from that square area, and calculate some value with them.

For instance, here are two plots below

plot at lat=80 long = 60

This picture clarifies the question. I need the diametrically opposite side also, so the latitude should again start to decrease from 90 towards 0, but then the longitudes will change again. In this way, I am going nowhere and stuck.

[image]

Plot at lat = 22 and long = 78

[image]

The 1st one becomes rectangular, and the 2nd one a square. How can I make them equal area with any given lat-long?

Even if I change the projection for the `set_extent` to `LCC` or any other, there is no way I can get to set the extent in terms of the center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is rather simple, I was completely misinterpreting how the Orthographic projection works. Projecting and setting the extent both in Orthographic projection will work fine. Here is the solution -

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 
x=float(input('Enter latitude:'))
y=float(input('Enter longitude:')) 
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Orthographic(y,x))
ax.set_extent((-1000000,1000000,-1000000,1000000),ccrs.Orthographic(y,x))
ax.coastlines('50m')
ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

plot at lat = 90 and long = 180

[image]

plot at lat=22 and long = 88

[image]

Both the maps clearly covers same area around the given latitude, longitude values.
Thanks!!!